# How Can I Draw Colorful Path in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-3

I work for a project about Google Maps and Traffic. 
I want to draw route but ı want it to be colorful for my situation.

How can I draw a route colorful same line ?

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: please include some code for what you have attempted so we know what language you are using.

Comment: What kind of line? Straight line or driving route?

Comment: @KanchanChowdhury driving route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PolylineOptions class to draw line then the following will help you:

```
 PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
 /* code for adding points ...   */
 lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
 // You can also use following
 // lineOptions.color(Color.parseColor("#ff00ff"));
```